# Calculate avg in subquery in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, subquery, average

```
points = Session.query(TeamMatchStats) \
    .join(TeamMatchStats.match) \
    .join(Match.league) \
    .filter(League.season == self.season) \
    .filter(TeamMatchStats.team == team) \
    .filter(Match.date <= date).limit(7).subquery()

points = Session.query(func.avg(points))
```

What's wrong with these two queries in order to calculate the avg of a column that needs to have a limit applied ?

Comment: `avg` is applied to a column, not a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`avg` must be used with a column. A subquery in SQLAlchemy is a core selectable, so you must use `.c` to access the columns. Here I assume `TeamMatchStats` has a points column:

```
points = Session.query(func.avg(points.c.points))
```